# disable any usb keyboard and mouse

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, mouse

I would like to disable any keyboard and mouse user puts in USB port (regardless their ID, vendor, name, ...). I found this article http://wpkg.org/Disable_/_enable_keyboard_and_mouse_in_Linux but it is not exactly what I am looking for. Any idea how to disable usb devices (keyboard, mouse, wireless keyboard/mouse) and leave usb port enabled just for usb mass storage?

Answer (score 8):

Create a file called, e.g., `usbhid.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d/` and add the following line:

```
blacklist usbhid
```

Then re-generate your initramfs with:

```
update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
```

or, if you want to rebuild the initramfs for all installed kernel versions:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

After you reboot, `usbhid.ko` will be prevented from loading.  This will persist for any new kernel versions you install until you either delete the `/etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf` file or comment out the `blacklist` line it contains (of course, you have to re-generate the initramfs again).

---

BTW if you need to attach a USB kbd/mouse to work on the console for any reason, you can `ssh` in and run (as root):

```
insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbhid.ko
```

and plug the keyboard/mouse into a usb socket.  Unlike `modprobe`, the `insmod` command ignores any entries (incl. `blacklist` and module options) in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

Don't forget to `rmmod usbhid` when you don't need to use the kbd/mouse any more.

Comment: this seems to be a nice solution in case, if I'd need kbd/mouse later. thank you, I will try it!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply remove the corresponding drivers:

```
sudo rm /lib/modules/<your_kernel>/kernel/drivers/hid/usbhid/*
```

(actually, you should rather move those drivers somewhere in case you'll want them back, but I hope you get the idea)

Comment: don't delete the modules, just add `blacklist usbhid` to a `.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d` and re-generate your initramfs - e.g. on debian `update-initramfs -u`.  when you reboot, `usbhid.ko` will be prevented from loading.

Comment: No, deleting the drivers is a BAD IDEA. What @cas said.

Comment: Thank you, I will try @cas solution. It seems to be more universal if I need to persist drivers.

Comment: @peter Of course, modifying the config file is the way to go. I'm glad I could find the right driver though.