# Disable all USB devices for all users

Tags: linux-mint, usb, users

### The Problem

Disable all communications on all USB ports for all users (preferably remove power but as I'll point out below I don't think this is possible). I'm currently using Linux Mint 18.

### What I Have Tried

- Disabling the power: [stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux)
- Blacklisting storage devices and removing all users from plugdev: [askubuntu.com/questions/153964](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153964/how-do-i-prevent-standard-users-from-using-the-usb-ports)
- Removing all drivers for USB ports: [ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692251](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692251)
- Searching for a method to turn off via the BIOS. No options available.
- Turning the laptop off and on again after each attempt.

None of the above seemed to work (tested by using a USB mouse & memory stick).

I haven't gotten round to trying the suggestion in [unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274203](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274203/disable-any-usb-keyboard-and-mouse) yet (which might disable keyboards and mice), however, allowing root to subvert blacklists is also not allowed.

I get the feeling that removal of drivers may be the best solution (placing in root for testing at least), but I'd need to know which drivers to target so that I don't break anything else.

I'd kind of prefer not having to get the soldering kit out to make a hardware adjustment if at all possible...

Comment: If you're going to vote me down could I at least have a reason for why?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to add the "nousb" option to the kernel boot line, either at boot, or editing the /etc/default/grub file or /boot/grub.cfg

RedHat 7 did this when selecting the DISA Stig security profile.  Took me a bit to figure out why my mouse and keyboard stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I have an option in the BIOS to disable all USB ports. I have disabled camera, microphone & bluetooth.

For security reasons is good to disable USB ports. Many companies do it. However if you want to do it in Linux, there is a driver called "usb-storage". Try removing it, or if not possible, try forbidding it (blacklisting it).

As said in the discussion, try blacklisting it. Go to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `blacklist usb-storage`

See the discussion in OpenSUSE: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/441492-how-to-disable-usb-storage

Comment: As referenced in the question, this should block storage devices only. However, I need to block all USB devices. Also, I have now tried implementing both the blacklisting of usb-storage and usbhid. Usbhid successfully prevents mice, however, usb sticks still mount and load for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a udev rule similar to this:

```
ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/usbdevinserted.sh"
```

And, in usbdevinserted.sh, add commands to lock access to this USB.

Also, you can remove users from `usb` group (or other group that provides access to usb devices)